# Assign which column to paste the copied data VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button in Worksheet1 that when clicked it will copy the values from A20:M28 to Worksheet2.
But I want to assign which column in Worksheet2 the values from Worksheet1 will be copied to because they have different structure. Also I wanted to copy only the rows that has values but it still copied the cells without values.
I am pretty new to Macro so I'm still trying to figure things out. This is what I have so far:

[Worksheet1 Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKv6B.png)

[Worksheet2 Structure & Result when button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83J5c.jpg)

```
Sub SendTimeTable()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook


 '## Open both workbooks first:
 Set ws1 = Application.ThisWorkbook
 Set ws2 = Workbooks.Open("workbook2.xlsm")

'Cells A20:A28
For i = 20 To 28
 'Column A to Column M
  For j = 1 To 13

   If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dataSheet1").Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then

   'Now, copy what you want from worksheet1 to worksheet2:
   ws1.Sheets("dataSheet1").Range("A20:M28").Copy
   ws2.Sheets("dataSheet2").Range("A10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End If


Next
Next      
End Sub
```

Comment: There are a few ways you can go about this, before I write an answer, I'd like to clarify the following: 1) You want to choose which cell the data will move to in sheet2 each time the button is pressed? Or you want to be able to have a dynamic reference to a destination? 2) You only want cells with data to be moved to the destination sheet (so blank cells are ignored)? 3) I can see there are some additional columns in sheet2 as opposed to sheet1, so am I right in assuming this format will be constant?

Comment: @SamuelEverson 1.) The cell that I want to copy to Sheet2 will always be A20:M28 of Sheet1. 2) Only rows with values will be copied. 3) yes the format of sheet2 & sheet1 is permanent :)

Comment: Sorry, with point number 1 I was meaning did you want to select the destination (you mentioned something about the column)?

Comment: oh sorry. Yes, I want to select the destination Column in worksheet2 :) @SamuelEverson

Comment: to correct the display of data in worksheet2 :)

Comment: Also the destination Worksheet2 is in Table.